# Simplify/speed up SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to make this query faster:

```
$qur = mysql_query("
 SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
 (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname = '$lastname') AS full FROM users 
 WHERE (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') 
 OR (firstname LIKE '$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '$lastname%')
 OR firstname LIKE '$firstname%' OR lastname LIKE '$firstname%'
 ORDER BY (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') DESC");
```

What I need in this:

```
Check if its a full match.
Get firstname lastname
Being able to only enter lastname "Fox" and let it find the firstname (get all users with lastname Fox, and show their firstname too and display check the script at bottom.)
Being able to only enter the firstname "Megan" and let it find the lastname (^)
Being able to only enter Megan F, and let it show "Megan Fox"
Being able to only enter Me Fox, and let it show "Megan Fox"
```

This is what it does to me, working without no problem. Although maybe I think this would run slow when alot of users run it

I'm using it with this:

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($qur) == 1) {

 $get = mysql_fetch_array($qur);
    if($get["full"] == 1){
    echo $get["id"];
    }else{
     echo "Did you mean: ".$get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"]." ?";
    }
 }elseif(mysql_num_rows($qur) > 1){
    while($get = mysql_fetch_array($qur)) {
       $name[] = $get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"];
   }

   if(count($name) > 1) {
       echo 'Who did you mean?<br>';
   } else {
       echo 'Did you mean: ';
   }
   echo implode('<br>', $name);

 }
```

Comment: Should not it be "CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS full" instead of "(firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname = '$lastname') AS full"?

Comment: @Paulo  I don't think that's what he's going for.  He wants a boolean equivalent for when there is a full match.

Comment: @Christopher W. Allen-Poole: thanks, I took full for "full name" instead of "full match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the query to:

```
$qur = mysql_query(
"SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
 (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname = '$lastname') AS full FROM users 
 WHERE firstname LIKE '$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '$lastname%' 
 ORDER BY (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') DESC");
```

`LIKE '...%'` here covers all the cases. But apart from that, maybe you should look into [MyISAM's FULLTEXT search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), that will probably yield better results.

PS: I hope you cave escaped `$firstname` and `$lastname` before inserting them in the query!

Answer (score 1):

look into [`lucene`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) (and [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)).  It'll make relevance queries like this much easier to work with.

Comment: There is nothing about relevance here. I don't know lucene, but I know Sphinx Search and that would be totally overkill in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL does not match your description, because the SQL will also find Megan McAllister when "Megan" and "F" ist entered because `OR firstname LIKE '$firstname%'` is enough to satisfy the condition.

Your description translates to SQL like this:

```
WHERE firstname LIKE '$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '$lastname%'
```

I think you have to put the "full match" logic in another SQL or you have to break out of the loop/iterate over the results in a first pass to check if it's a full match. Think of the case when there is a Mega Fox and a Megana Foxy: You will get two rows, although there *is* a full match.

Here's a suggestion for a "full match" logic:

```
unset($name); unset($id);

while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($qur))
{
    $name []= $get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"];
    if ($get['full'])
    {
        $id = $get['id'];
        break;
    }
}

if ($id)
    echo $id;
elseif ($name)
    echo implode('<br>', $name);
else
    echo 'Nothing found';
```

Comment: It would be far easier and far more consistent to break this up into a couple of different queries with fall over conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer AndreKR. Ok forget about my query then, how would you make this quer(ies) if you should fill the description? Could you show me using another SQL for the full match and so?

Comment: It's just the WHERE I gave in the answer. And for the logic I updated the answer (for I don't think code formatting works in comments) with a suggestion.
And please pay attention that you use addslashes and htmlentities.